# How to capture "ReferenceError: Can't find variable"

Tags: javascript

I have the following Code:

```
if(AdMob) { ... }
```

Then I get the error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable AdMob

How to capture this error that I don't see it in the console anymore?

EDIT:
Why `AdMob` is not just `falsy` and I'm not getting any error.

Comment: What kind of capture do you expect ? You want to get the error in a variable ? Why not try/catch then ?

Comment: I think you are using some external javascript library to implement `Ads` that library defines the `AdMob` variable. So make sure you are referencing that library in your project correctly.

Comment: @gurehbgui You've not declared AdMob anywhere. Only when a variable is declared you can access it. If the variable is not even declared then it will give you reference error as there is no reference for it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real way to avoid errors being logged is to put the code in a try/catch block.

```
try {
    if(AdMob){
    }
} catch(e){
}
```

Verify it does not result in errors on this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvej1r5k/)

Of course you could solve it as easy as defining the variable (assuming this should not be a global variable):

```
var AdMob;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try { 
 if(AdMob) { } 
}
catch(err){
  //Do something here
}
```

or you can throw custom exception

```
try { 
 if(AdMob) { } 
}
catch(err){
  throw new Error("Error: AdMob is not defined");  
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use try-catch to capture the error

```
try {

if (AdMob) {

}

} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: You are assuming `AdMob` should be a global variable. This won't work if it's a local variable.

Comment: You simply don't attempt to answer the question. Please read it.

Comment: If the OP's asking to avoid the error being logged, I would advise not to log it in the catch clause...